# UPS rate request using .net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, ups

I have an existing web service using .NET C#.  Our in house application call the service and the service connects to UPS using XML to handle the request.  It stopped working a few weeks ago.  I connect to UPS and they said to update the URLs which I have done.  They also mentioned they were seeing lots of TLS failure for but our IIS 8 and Windows Server 2012 are both up to date.  I also have run security checks and both SSL3 and TLS have been disabled.

On my development system I am attempting to test the changes.  First I wrote a small console application which connect to the UPS servers, this worked as expected.  I move the code to the web service and ran the same test and it fails.  I have verified the web service and the console code are running the same version of .NET.

I have compared the data sent so I am sure both are valid.  The error occurs at shipRequest.GetRequestStream().  Any idea why it is failing on the web service but not the console app?

I just added the ServerCertificateValidationCallback part, it does not work if removed with the same error.

Rate_Tool_SampleRequest.xml was downloaded from the UPS development site.

```
internal string UPSAccessKey;
internal string UPSPassword;
internal string UPSUserID;
internal string UPSAccount;
internal string Server = "https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate";
// test file, to be removed.
private static string RateFile = @"D:\Projects\UPS-Tracking\samples\Rate_Tool_SampleRequest.xml";

internal string GetRates(UPS_RateEstimate request)
{
    try
    {
       // var data = this.AccessRequest + request.Data;

        // Read UPS test file and replace key filds
        var data = File.ReadAllText(RateFile)
            .Replace("Your_License", UPSAccessKey)
            .Replace("Your_ID", UPSPassword)
            .Replace("Your_Password", UPSUserID)
            .Replace("Ship Number", UPSAccount);

        var response = this.RequestData(data);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc);
        return exc.ToString();
    }
}

private string RequestData(string request)
{
    HttpWebRequest shipRequest;
    try
    {
        // convert request to bytes
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(request); // Request
        shipRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Server);
        shipRequest.Method = "POST";
        shipRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        shipRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        shipRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, error) => { return true; };
        using (var requestStream = shipRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            // Send the data
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            using (var response = shipRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    File.WriteAllText(RateTestResultFile, result);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        shipRequest = null;
    }
}

System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
    ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at UPSHelper.RequestData(String request) in \App_Code\UPS\UPSHelper.cs:line 99
   at UPSHelper.GetRates(UPS_RateEstimate request) in \App_Code\UPS\UPSHelper.cs:line 34
```

Comment: Google how to use this: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Crowcoder, Tls12 works as well as Tls11.  Note the .net platform must be set to 4.5 or above.

Comment: That works for me too. Thanks Crowcoder & John Hughes!

Answer (score 0):

I think namely you are missing this line:

Here is a full code example:

```
        string Testing = "https://wwwcie.ups.com/rest/Rate";
        string Production = "https://onlinetools.ups.com/rest/Rate";
        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(upsRate);
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11; //This line will ensure the latest security protocol for consuming the web service call.
        WebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(Production);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        string returnResult = "";
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            returnResult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnResult))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(returnResult);
```

NOTE: I am serializing a UPSRate object whereas you are reading the properties from a file it looks like.